# Mongoose Pre Command not working as Expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi I am New to Mongoose And trying to use pre command to Convert a given password in String to Hash values before saving it in the database. I am not Getting any Syntax error but my password is not getting converted into Hash IDS.

My Controller Code is as follows:

```
User.save(req.body,function(err,data){
      if (err) {
         res.json({
             sucess:false,
             exception:err
         });
      } 
    else{
     res.json({
             sucess:true,
             User:data
         });

    }
});

    User.pre('save',function(next){
       bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt){
                 if(err){
                     return res.json({
                           success:false,
                           exception:err
                     }); 
                 }
                  bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                  if(err){
                        return res.json({
                           success:false,
                           exception:err
                     }); 
                  }
                 password=hash;
              });
          });  
        next();     

   });
```

Using Node inspector I found out that command line is not entering the User.pre .So Can somebody let me know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: User must be your schema, is it? Or is it the model? replace string password = hash; to this.password = hash

Comment: User is a model in my code.

Comment: See the original - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's various things wrong with your code, the main part being that hooks should be attached to the *schema* and not the *model*, which seems to be what you're doing.

Also, it looks like you're trying to add a pre-save hook for every request, which is not how hooks are supposed to work: they should be declared just once, on the schema (as said above) and *before* you create the model.

The order should be similar to this:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(...);

UserSchema.pre('save', ...);

var User = mongoose.Model(UserSchema);
```

This means that you can't send an error response from your pre-save hook, as you're trying to do now, but you don't really want that anyway IMO (you should keep your Mongoose schema/models separated from your Express route handlers). Instead, catch any errors that are thrown during `.save()` and handle them there.

To give an idea on what a proper hook might look like, here's an example (I took a guess as to your `User` schema so it may be using the wrong field names):

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var document = this;
  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(document.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      document.password = hash;
      next();   
    });
  });  
});
```